# How to pass through a incomming http call to another server in dart?

Tags: stream, dart, pipe, backend

I have a Dart HTTP-service running and if the service gets a file posted I want to pass-through this call to another service. I think pipes are the right way, but I have no idea I could do this?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have received an incoming request, then the client has a TCP connection with your server. You can't just forward that to another server.

What you can do is to return a 301 Redirect response which should make the requester try the other server instead.

The alternative is to fetch the data from the other server yourself and deliver it as a response to the original request. You can use a stream pipe for that.

Something like:

```
Future handleRequest(HttpRequest request) {
  return new HttpClient()  // Or reuse an existing client if it happens often
      .getUrl(createOtherServerUrl(request))
      .then((newRequest) => newRequest.close())
      .then((response) => response.pipe(request.response));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are a command line shell feature.

When your server receives a request it can create a new request to the "another server" and send the data received from the incoming request to this "another server".

[shelf_proxy](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf_proxy) might help you doing that.

Comment: ... and "pipe" are methodes to pass trough a stream to an stream handler  
[Dart Doc](https://api.dartlang.org/133432/dart-async/Stream/pipe.html)
  

and this is what i want to do. but without buffer all the incomming data locally... i want to pass through (piping) the incomming call directly to the other http-service

Comment: Sure the pipes are a very generic concept, I assumed you know them from command line. Streams in Dart have a `pipe()` function. If you have an incoming stream and an outgoing stream you can use `outgoing.pipe(incoming)` to forward the data. You still have to create a new request to the "another service" to get an outgoing stream in the first place.